# Compilation vs translation, "compiling" Java to bytecode?

Tags: java, compilation, compiler-theory

My understanding is like this, definitions:

*Translation* - having code in some language, generating code in some other language.

*Compilaton* - translation to a machine code.

*Machine code* - direct instructions for CPU.

Now, from [docs.oracle.com](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javac.html):

> javac - Java programming language *compiler*

Compiler...? I think it is Java *translator*, because it is generating a code, that is not a machine code. Bytecode needs interpreter (JVM) to run, so it's definetely not a machine code.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_%28programming_language%29):

> Java applications are typically *compiled* to bytecode

Similarly. According to definitions, I would say that Java is *traslated* to bytecode. There are many more examples on the Internet, I think there is confusion about that or I'm just missing something.

Could you please clarify this?
**What is the difference between translation and compilation?**

Comment: Your definitions are wrong.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**It's all a matter of definitions**, and there's **no single accepted definition for what "compilation" means**. In your eyes, compilation is transforming a source code in some language to native; so a transformation process which doesn't generate machine code shouldn't be called "compilation". In my eyes (and apparently, the `javac` documentation writers' eyes as well), it should.

There are actually a lot of different terms: translation, compilation, decompilation, assembly, disassembly, and more.

Personally, I'd say it makes sense to group all of these terms under "compilation", because all these processes have a lot in common:

- They transform code in one formal language to code in another formal language.
- They try to preserve the semantics of the input code as much as possible.
- They all have a very similar design to each other, with a front-end, a back-end, and a possible optimizer in the middle ([learn more about compiler structure here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler)). I've seen the entrails of both `javac` and native compilers and they are relatively similar.

In addition, your definition of "produces native code" is problematic:

- What about compilers that can generate assembly but don't bother transforming that to machine code, leaving this to an external program (commonly called "assembler")? Would you deny them this definition of "compilers" because of that last, insignificant-in-comparison step?
- How do you even classify "machine code"? What if tomorrow [a processor which can run Java Bytecode natively is created](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jazelle)?

But these are just my opinions. I think that out there, **the most accepted definitions** are that:

- **Compilation** is transforming code in a higher-level language to a lower-level one. Examples: Java to Java Bytecode, or C to x86 machine code.
- **Decompilation** is transforming a code in a lower-level language to a higher-level one - in effect, the opposite of compilation. Examples: Java Bytecode to Java.
- **Translation** or **source-to-source compilation** is transforming a code in some language to another language of comparable "level". Examples: ARM to x86, or C to Java. When the two languages are actually different versions of the same language (e.g. Javascript 6 to Javascript 5), the term **transpiler** is also used.
- **Assembly** is transforming code in some assembly language to machine code.
- **Disassembly** is either a synonym to decompilation or the opposite of assembly, depending on the context.

Under these definitions, `javac` could definitely be considered as a compiler. But again, it's all in the definitions: from a technical standpoint, many of these actions have a lot in common.

Answer (score 5):

The result of javac is machine code. The fact that the machine is virtual and not physical is not relevant (otherwise, you could argue that compiling code in x86 was translation if you were a Mac user, since the x86 code is not Mac machine code).

Comment: Since 2006 Macs use the x86 platform

Comment: Why not *translate* from C++ to x86 and then *compile* from x86 to PowerPC machine code? I think it is better then putting bytecode == machine code. How x86 machine code could be in the same class as bytecode...

Comment: There is no such language as x86.  You could translate C++ to machine language but this would still need to be compiled to machine code.  A language is text based for a human developer and is abstracted from the actual machine.  Machine code is something the CPU can run.

Comment: I think we have different definitions of *language*. I think that *language* doesn't have to be text based. Language is operating on symbols. 01 or text (or voices), doesn't matter. Human also can read 01 instructions.

Comment: Then, by that definition, **everything** is a language,  you never compile and always translate. Not an useful definition if it serves to all.

Comment: No, you compile, if you are translating to a machine code (which is a language by symbolic definition).

Comment: More useful is putting bytecode == machine code? What if we have 5 virtual machines? On the abstract first we write a code which is translated to the second one less abstract, and so on... So, we should say "compiled" not "translated"? I think it's more confusing. The last translation in that 5 virtual machines model will be a compilation (according to the definitions I gave).

Comment: With your definition you will 5 times (always) "compile", never "translate".

Comment: You know, I'm not arguing with you, I'm learning, trying to understand this :) You are more experienced then me, so if my definition of for example "language" is wrong (i.e. most of the people understands it in a way you told me) - that's ok :) But I heard this symbolic definition and it all seems to work fine with it. So I'm just curious, maybe its like legacy? Some time ago somebody just named it `javac` and with a time everybody just get used to it, get definitions which will stick to "compiling java to bytecode" etc.

Answer (score 1):

> "A compiler is a computer program (or set of programs) that transforms
>   source code written in a programming language (the source language)
>   into another computer language (the target language, often having a
>   binary form known as object code)."

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler

So no a compilation doesn't mean that the output is in machine code.
For example early C++ compilation would generate a C program, that then needed to be compiled again into machine code. Of course any good compiler would hide these separate steps from the user, but they are still there.

Nowday I know at least of the NesC compiler that does the same procedure.

A machine that runs JVM bytecode can be built, actually some chapters of  Structured Computer Organization, from A. Tanenbaum describe how to do that.

[http://www.amazon.com/Structured-Computer-Organization-5th-Edition/dp/0131485210](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131485210)

Comment: Compilation == translation? So, all the translators should be called compilers instead?

Comment: Translation is more generic, I could translate from English to Spanish, and I wouldn't call that compiling, but in the area of computer languages, yes absolutely.

Answer (score 1):

> Compiler...? I think it is Java translator, because it is generating a code, that is not a machine code. Bytecode needs interpreter (JVM) to run, so it's definetely not a machine code.

The JVM is the *Java Virtual Machine*, which is a machine, and its machine code is called Java byte code. (Each "byte" in byte code is a JVM machine instruction.)

You can learn more by reading the JVM specification. Start here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/

Also, **the JVM is not an interpreter**; it is a *definition* of a machine. Some *implementations* of the JVM include just-in-time (JIT) compilers, ahead-of-time (AOT) compilers, adaptive compilers (e.g. Hotspot), and yes, even interpreters (although I haven't personally seen a Java interpreter in 20 years now).

What most people starting out in compilers don't understand is that there are no compilers anymore that generate "machine code". They all generate some intermediate forms (as defined by a particular OS, for example) that are then loaded and munged by the OS.

**For the most part today, *no* compiled program is capable of being executed without a large, bloated OS to munge it and slice it and glue it into pieces that the OS owns and manages.**

Not even C compiles code into actual machine executables nowadays without coloring outside the lines. (Write an actual, working boot loader from scratch, and get back to me.)